# Get previous filename with NodeJS fs.watch rename action

Tags: node.js, filesystems

Is it possible to get the previous name of a renamed file, using fs.watch in NodeJS? For example:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.watch("some_file",function(action,filename){
    if (action == "rename" && filename)
        console.log("what was the old filename, before the rename action?");
});
```

Comment: I actually get the old filename by default and have problems to get the new one...

Comment: @Ini I'm not sure about that— better to ask a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only on Windows and Linux.  On OS X the kernel doesn't support the necessary functionality to send back the filename to your callback.

Oh, I misunderstood the question.  You don't want to see the new name.  You want to get the old name.

The API doesn't support that at the moment that I know of.

Comment: Apparently, (at least on linux), it fires your handler twice: once with the old file (rename or delete), and once with the new file (if renaming).